# Sybase SQL Query Clarification

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

I have a sybase sql query and its returning an integer as the result.

Can anyone explain the logic of this query.

```
select b.length 
from sysobjects a, syscolumns b
where a.name = 'StuComm' 
and a.id = b.id and b.name = 'StuCD'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm kinda unsure what you are asking here, but I'll take a stab at it.

This query is finding the length of the `StuCD` column in the `StuComm` table.  It's pulling the information from `sysobjects` and `syscolumns`

`length` is a column in syscolumns of type `int`, which is why you get an integer result.  The length is the value that the datatype is declared with, so a column with declared as a `varchar(255)` will have a length of 255.